# Object is possibly undefined when I'm handling those scenarios

Tags: typescript

```
const id = myMap.has(key) ? myMap.get(key) : "defaultValue"

if (id.includes("stuff")) { // Compiler complains saying "Object is possibly undefined"
```

I don't understand how this object can ever be undefined. If it has the key, it gets the value. If it doesn't, the result is "defaultValue". It should cover all cases, why is this complaining?

Comment: `const myMap = new Map(); myMap.set("stuff", undefined);`. Well, `myMap` definitely *has* that key, and the value is indeed `undefined`.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm trying to avoid using postfix operator `!` because I want to let the compiler do its job, but if `myMap` is defined by me with a list of constants and will never contain `undefined` then maybe this use-case is justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should cover all cases

It doesn't:

```ts
const myMap = new Map<string, any>();
myMap.set("stuff", undefined);
const id = myMap.has(key) ? myMap.get(key) : "defaultValue";
id.includes("default"); // BOOM!
```

Note that it doesn't get any better if we avoid `any`. You could always call it with an unknown string key at runtime, which the compiler knows and it has no way to verify that the accesses are always valid.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using postfix operator ! because I want to let the compiler do its job, but if myMap is defined by me with a list of constants and will never contain undefined then maybe this use-case is justified?

Comment: If it really is constant, then use an object instead of a map and then you won't have to do the conditional check at all (which *should* be superfluous if the data is really const). You are correct that using the postfix operator is a bad habit. If it isn't totally const then you can just do this instead which is safe: `id?.includes("stuff")`